# Why does the work done depend on the frame of reference?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, energy, reference-frames, work

If I pushes a box due east for 1m by a 10 newtons of force, the work I do is 1J. But, if I consider the Earth's own rotation, the box actually has moved about 1km, and the work becomes more than 1000J. If I choose the frame of reference of a far away star, I might have done a billion joules of work. It seems that work done depends on the frame of reference I take.

**But this doesn't make sense.** If work equals to energy transformed, then do I spend 10J of energy or a billion joules of energy to push that box? Clearly I don't have 1000000000J in my body.

Why does the formula led to this conclusion?

Comment: Are you also taking into account the energy of yourself in those different perspectives? To a distant object you also might have billions of joules of kinetic energy...some of which can do useful work.

Comment: The amount of energy in a body changes between frames—if you do a Lorentz boost to chase a moving object until it stops moving, then its energy is reduced, so the above statement must be true. Work done is just differences in energy, so it must also be changing between frames. This is simply a necessity.

Comment: @Triatticus That is interesting, but how does my kinetic energy do work? If I have no kinetic energy, I can still push a box using chemical energy in my muscle. I think I should use the same kind of energy when I am moving.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent I understand that kinetic energy changes between frames, but when I do work, I am converting other kinds of energy into kinetic energy. I might do 10J or billions of joules of work, but the chemical energy used in my body should be constant.

Comment: I am trying to tell you that the fact that kinetic energy changes between frames, means that all other energies will also do the same. However, the specific examples you are talking about, the energies are just coming from elsewhere. Triatticus and Chad K are trying to tell you that you need to properly consider the examples you raised, and you can discover where actually the energies are coming from. Your initial analysis is just too sloppy.

Comment: @Max492 what naturallyinconsistent stated plus it's the work energy theorem, the work done is at the cost of other energies like kinetic and internal.

Comment: @naturallyInconsistent Ok thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A force perpendicular to velocity doesn't do any work.  Work is the change in kinetic energy, so
$$\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{1}{2}m \vec{v}\cdot\vec{v}\right) = m\vec{v}\cdot\vec{a} = \vec{v}\cdot\vec{F}$$
So the work a force does only depends on its projection along the direction of the velocity.  If you push a box perpendicular to gravity, there is no work done by the gravity.  If you push a box parallel to gravity, there is work done by you *and* work done by the gravity.  In the example you gave, if there's any work done in parallel to gravity, that additional work is done by gravity, not by you.