# Electric potential and Magnetic Potential

Tags: electromagnetism, potential

I have seen that there exists an intimate relationship between electric and magnetic properties. From what I know is that electric field creates  electric potential around the source's space which can allow a charged particle to gain some PE and makes it possible for that particle to have translational and rotational motion. I have searched quite a bit and could see that magnetic potential energy can only cause rotational motion, why not translational motion?

Comment: have you ever held two pieces of magnets on a table and see if they could move *towards* each other when let loose?

Answer (score 0):

The Lorenz force on a point charge $q$ is $\vec{F} = q\vec{E} + q\vec{v}\times\vec{B}$.

$\vec{v} \cdot (\vec{v}\times \vec{B})=0$ by the scalar triple product, so the force on a point charge contributed by a magnetic field is always perpendicular to the velocity.  A force perpendicular to velocity does not change the kinetic energy as calculated [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/789751/385038).  So it cannot change the speed, only rotate the particle.

Now, magnetic dipoles are a different story.  They're made up from little current loops, and current loops can pull each other by magnetic field.  This is summarized [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_dipole#Forces_between_two_magnetic_dipoles).  It may seem like an anomaly, but there are electrical forces at work keeping the current loops rigid, and in doing so converting what would otherwise be rotational motion to translational motion.